# regex to match pattern and last empty line in a file

Tags: regex

I'm having regex to match [pattern like this](https://regex101.com/r/GEzzNo/1):

```
\AX.*(?:\r?\n[KLM].*)*\r?\nZ.*(?:\r?\nX.*(?:\r?\n[KLM].*)*\r?\nZ.*)*\z
```

Is there any way I could match same pattern with one extra line updating same regex ?

```
    A---Header
    K
    L
    M
    Z---Footer
--> empty line. No characters and spaces are there
```

I have tried options by by doing some google..but this could not work.

Any suggestion

Thanks !!

Comment: [Replace `\z` with `$`](https://regex101.com/r/GEzzNo/3). Or with [`\r?\n\z`](https://regex101.com/r/GEzzNo/2).

Comment: not working !! check this https://regex101.com/r/6Egh7C/1

Comment: You mean there can be *many* empty lines? Just add `(?:\r?\n)*` before `\z`.

Comment: Since Java 8 line separators can be represented as `\R`, no need for `\r?\n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `\z` anchor matches at the very end of the string. To match a string that can end with 0 or more empty lines, add `(?:\r?\n)*` before `\z`:

```
\AX.*(?:\r?\n[KLM].*)*\r?\nZ.*(?:\r?\nX.*(?:\r?\n[KLM].*)*\r?\nZ.*)*(?:\r?\n)*\z
                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6Egh7C/2)

If your string can have a `\n` symbol at the end, you may just replace `\z` with `$` (since `$` can match before the final newline symbol in the string, while `\z` matches exactly the end of  string).